# Regular Expressions in java trying to match a string in specific format (format consists of | sysbol)

Tags: java, regex, hbase

Regular Expressions in java

```
String s1="Anil-anilorg|anotherorg";
String s2="Anil-anilorg|";
```

I want to find weather s2 is present or sub-string of s1 by using regular expressions, but while I am doing that it is considering this symbol  "|" as logical OR
I am using `hbaseStringRegexComparator` to compare

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the | as \|, and within a String it becomes `"\\|"`.

Comment: can you please explain me why do it need two back \\?

Comment: Within a string literal the backslash is the escape symbol. A single backslash will escape the logical or symbol and the regex will consequently contain just it. A double backslash will escape the backslash so the regex with contain \| as required.

Comment: Thank you it worked

Answer (score 1):

You can use String.contains method. No regex needed:

```
    String s1="Anil-anilorg|anotherorg"; 
    String s2="Anil-anilorg|"; 
    System.out.println(s1.contains(s2));
```